# Bootbox dialog is not shown

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootbox

I'm using Bootstrap 2.3.1 and Bootbox version 3.3.0. When I write the following code:

```
bootbox.dialog({message:"test"});
```

empty modal window appears. If I use 'alert' method of bootbox everything works fine. I tested it in Safari(6.0.3) and Firefox (24.0).

Has anybody faced with this problem?

Tamara.

Answer (score 2):

Bootbox 3.x doesn't accept object arguments. You'll have to upgrade to Bootstrap 3 and Bootbox 4.x for that.

Here's an example of a Bootbox 3.x dialog:

```
var boxContentString = "html formatted text goes here";
bootbox.dialog(boxContentString,[
    //buttons
    {
        "label" : "Button 1",
        "class" : "btn-success",
        "callback": function(e){
            //do stuff
        }   
    },
    {
        "label" : "Button 2",
        "callback": function(e){
            //do stuff
        }
    }
]);
```

Here's a link for the [Bootbox 3 Documentation](http://bootboxjs.com/v3.x/documentation.html)